# Setting barcode bar width in zxing writer

Tags: java, barcode, zxing

I need to add barcode bar size while generating barcode in `zxing` library's  `Code128writer`.

I read the code and documentation but didn't find a suitable way.

These are the Hint Parameters which Code128writer.encode takes:

```
ERROR_CORRECTION,
```

/**
   * Specifies what character encoding to use where applicable (type {@link String})
   */

```
  CHARACTER_SET,
```

/**
   * Specifies the matrix shape for Data Matrix (type {@link com.google.zxing.datamatrix.encoder.SymbolShapeHint})
   */

```
  DATA_MATRIX_SHAPE,
```

/**
   * Specifies a minimum barcode size (type {@link Dimension}). Only applicable to Data Matrix now.
   */

```
  MIN_SIZE,
```

/**
   * Specifies a maximum barcode size (type {@link Dimension}). Only applicable to Data Matrix now.
   */

```
  MAX_SIZE,
```

/**
   * Specifies margin, in pixels, to use when generating the barcode. The meaning can vary
   * by format; for example it controls margin before and after the barcode horizontally for
   * most 1D formats. (Type {@link Integer}).
   */

```
  MARGIN,
```

/**
   * Specifies whether to use compact mode for PDF417 (type {@link Boolean}).
   */

```
  PDF417_COMPACT,
```

/**
   * Specifies what compaction mode to use for PDF417 (type
   * {@link com.google.zxing.pdf417.encoder.Compaction Compaction}).
   */

```
  PDF417_COMPACTION,
```

/**
   * Specifies the minimum and maximum number of rows and columns for PDF417 (type
   * {@link com.google.zxing.pdf417.encoder.Dimensions Dimensions}).
   */

```
  PDF417_DIMENSIONS,
```

/**
   * Specifies the required number of layers for an Aztec code:
   *   a negative number (-1, -2, -3, -4) specifies a compact Aztec code
   *   0 indicates to use the minimum number of layers (the default)
   *   a positive number (1, 2, .. 32) specifies a normaol (non-compact) Aztec code
   */

```
   AZTEC_LAYERS,
```

Is such an option available in this library or if you can recommend another library?

I tried Barbecue but it takes pixels(int) as input and I need pixels in float.